# Reducing space in svjour documentclass

Tags: vertical-spacing

im using `\documentclass{svjour3}` and i need to reduce some spaces.

Heres a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author}

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Could anyone help me reduce the vertical space between the top blackline and the title, and also between the authors and the received date line?

[image: These red spaces in this picture]

Comment: Springer takes care of typesetting and layout.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am not goint to submit anything, it's just to show to some colleagues. I have tried `\vspace` and `\vskip`, but couldn't make it work.